# Exception in getting all followers with tweetsharp

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I use tweetsharp 2.3.1. When i try to get all followers from some account, i have null refernce exception with "ids" variable. What's wrong with it?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TwitterClientInfo tci = new TwitterClientInfo();
        tci.ConsumerKey = "***";
        tci.ConsumerSecret = "***";

        TwitterService ts = new TwitterService(tci);

        var options = new ListFollowersOptions { ScreenName = "***" };
        var ids = ts.ListFollowers(options);

        foreach (var id in ids) //there is an exception here
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(id.ScreenName);
        }
    }
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Presumably `ids` is null... does the account not have followers, perhaps?

Comment: account has followers, i tested code in different accounts

Comment: So the exception is really just a corollary of the *real* problem, which is that `ListFollowers` is returning `null`. Do other operations work? I've seen TweetSharp return null if the authorization token has timed out.

Comment: i tried to get some account setting such as screenName, timeZone, but it returned null refernce exception too... i suspect that i should add smth in code, but i don't know what